# Parsing HTML/XML tags using regular expressions

Tags: xml, regex, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

why is not a good idea to use regex for HTML/XML parsing?

Comment: Look at this answer, it contains detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/787016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because those languages aren't regular. They don't fit the intended use of regular expressions. It's much better to use something like XPath for XML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it: HTML/XML is a Chomsky Type 2 grammar while regular expressions are a Chomsky Type 3 grammar, so the latter hasn't sufficient expressive power to parse the former.